# как сделать так, чтобы виджет всегда добавлялся в начало первой строки на GridStack.js

Tags: grid

виджет всегда добавляется в конце, после последнего виджета

Допустим, у нас есть 10 виджетов, мы добавляем еще один, и он должен появиться вверху, перед самым первым добавленным

как сделать, чтобы виджет всегда добавлялся в начало, есть ли какие-то настройки для этого?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201290/gridstack-js-placing-some-items-in-specific-locations-while-populating-the-res